# Show that this (cosine) map is the logistic map as $ a \to \infty$

Tags: limits

I'm struggling with the following problem:

> Given the map:
>
> $$x_{n+1} = \frac{r}{4} \left( (a+1)\cos{\left[ k \left(x_n - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right]} - a \right),$$
>
> where $k = 2 \arccos{ \left( \frac{a}{a+1} \right)}$, $a > 0$,
>
> Show that in the limit $a \rightarrow \infty$, this map is the logistic map:
>
> $$x_{n+1} = rx_n \left( 1 - x_n \right)$$

So far, I've attempted the problem in steps: first, that $\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{a}{a+1} = 1$, so $\lim_{a \to \infty} k = \arccos{(1)} = 0$. But if it is true that in the limit $k=0$, then the result is absent of any $x_n$, and is obviously incorrect.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong, or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the limit of one piece of the expression and then substituting without considering the other parts that involve $a$ won't give you the correct answer.

Try substituting $t = a^{-1}$ and take the limit as $t \to 0$. You should identify an opportunity to turn the expression into a quotient of two functions of $t$, and then apply L'Hopital's Rule:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}
\end{equation}

Provided that you check that your $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable over $t >0$ (which follows from $a > 0$), and that $g'(t) \neq 0$ over $t>0$ as well.

Good luck!

Ken